# Freezing during stream out large files

Tags: php

Use `fread()` can stream large file to force download.
However, during the streaming, all php request will be blocked until the streaming finished. How can I process incoming requist during the streaming process?

Comment: are you using apache? if so look at mod_xsendfile for large files: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: Do you mean that if the streaming is running at `streaming.php` and i call `anotherpage.php` the latter won't run until the streaming is over?

Comment: Call `session_write_close` before `fread`.

Comment: @GhostGambler Post as answer, I will accept it. :) thanks

Comment: @STTLCU yes. the answer is below

Answer (score 1):

If one uses `session_start` to utilize the session functionality for the scripts and one does not change any default values then the default behavior is file-based session handling.

Files can only be opened by open process at a time. Thus if a script is started and calls `session_start` then this specific session file is locked. If another requests with the same session id is started, the next call to `session_start` is suspended until the file lock is free for locking again.

Under normal circumstances this is no problem at all, since there are rarely multiple requests with the same session id in a short time interval, but if one request executes abnormally long e.g. because it transfers huge amount of data back to the calling client, then the file lock is acquired considerably long.

Fortunately in most cases the session is not even needed anymore at this time of execution, therefore the session can be closed earlier as the end of the script, and the file lock is being released. After that one can e.g. transfer a huge amount of data without interfering other requests with the same session id.

Another way to solve this issue is to switch to database based session handling. Some more thoughts must be spend in this case to not lose written data, but in general this is possible.